# Azure Storage and Data Management

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have shutdown the VM in Azure Portal and the status was "Stopped(Deallocated)" but their was a billing process alive for Storage and Data Management, Do anyone know how to Stop these to avoid Billing.

Answer (score 3):

As you may already know, VHDs containing OS and Data disks for your VM are stored as Page Blobs in your Azure Storage account. One of the things you get charged for in Azure Storage is how much storage you're using and this is what you're getting charged for.

Deallocating the VM will only stop the billing for the VM.

To stop the billing for the storage, you would need to delete the page blobs holding your OS/Data disks. You can accomplish the same by deleting the VM.

Please note that if you delete these blobs, you're essentially losing everything for that VM and you will need to start from scratch if you ever need the VM again.

Comment: so you are saying that these cannot be stopped and kept billing, the only way to stop is to delete the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Gaurav Mantri

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop it as you already already using storage which has fees to pay, specially the VM size is large, but the storage cost is low.

When you shutdown the VM, it just stop the computing fee, but not the storage.

if you want to completely stop it, then delete the VM and its disks and have a scheduled Job or a part of an automation runbook to create the VM, deploy everything and start it, this will be doable for the VMs that has only files, but for VMs that has data like SQL, this will not be feasible as you will loose your data